# What am I wrong? about 'one-line FOR statement' and 'EXEC'

Tags: python, for-loop, exec

```
        r = []
        for e in self.leftCounter[0]:
            r.append(0)
        for i in self.leftCounter:
            r = map(operator.__add__, r, i)
        self.leftCounter = r

        r = []
        for e in self.rightCounter[0]:
            r.append(0)
        for i in self.rightCounter:
            r = map(operator.__add__, r, i)
        self.rightCounter = r

        r = []
        for e in self.neutralCounter[0]:
            r.append(0)
        for i in self.neutralCounter:
            r = map(operator.__add__, r, i)
        self.neutralCounter = r
```

Hi, I'm python newbie(and also programming language). I thought about this long time by myself, but finally I decided to ask. The code above works fine for me. But when I'm trying to change to the code below, It does not work. And moreover there is no specific error message. It just give me the message like 'invalid syntax (, line 1)'. I'm using version 2.7.6.

```
        r = []
        for i in ['self.leftCounter', 'self.rightCounter', 'self.neutralCounter']:
            exec '[r.append(0) for e in %s[0]]' % i
            exec '[r = map(operator.__add__, r, i) for i in %s]' % i
            exec '%s = r' % i
```

Can someone give me a hint please?
Thank you.

Comment: You want hint? Never use `exec`, unless that is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `exec`. Use [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) instead:

```
for name in ['leftCounter', 'rightCounter', 'neutralCounter']:
    r = getattr(self, name)[0]
    for i in getattr(self, name):
        r = map(operator.__add__, r, i)
    setattr(self, name, r)
```

If your input list really is static, you *could* just store direct references to the attributes:

```
for attr in (self.leftCounter, self.rightCounter, self.neutralCounter):
    r = attr[0]
    for i in attr:
        r = map(operator.__add__, r, i)
    attr[:] = r
```

where it is assumed that all three attributes are always lists, allowing us to use slice assignment to replace the *contents* of each list instead of rebinding.

Comment: Thank you very much Martijin Pieters, I will study about getattr() and setattr(). It really helped me! (I will accept the answer after 8 minutes)

Comment: Why use string representations of the attributes in the first place?

Comment: @wim: Actually, you can do a slice assignment, adding now.